# How to get the git log of which files were deleted/modified?

Tags: git, git-log

I could parse `git log -p --pretty=format:%H` but this also includes the content of the files.

Is there any option I could pass to `git log` that would return less characters than the command above but would still allow me to figure out whether at least 1 file was deleted or modified for each commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `--numstat` option:

> Similar to `--stat`, but shows number of added and deleted lines in
>   decimal notation and pathname without abbreviation, to make it more
>   machine friendly. For binary files, outputs two `-` instead of saying `0 0`.

So it would be:

```
git log --pretty=%H --numstat
```

If you're not interested in the exact number of lines, you can use the `--name-status` option:

> Show only names and status of changed files.

```
git log --pretty=%H --name-status
```

At that point you can simply parse the `M` and `D` statuses for *modified* and *deleted* files.

Comment: numstat won't help, because it doesn't distinguish between added files, and files where some lines were added. but --name-status was exactly what i was looking for